@JdbcTypeCode issue with Hibernate 6.x version
I am currently using Hibernate 6.4.4 version, along with spanner-hibernate-dialect 3.3.0 version and google-cloud-spanner-jdbc 2.16.1 version. But still facing the below error as:
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Could not deserialize string to java type: JsonJavaType(model.Template)
@Column(name="TemplateObj")
@JdbcTypeCode( SqlTypes.JSON )
private Template template;

Below is the model class of Template
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Template {
    private String id;
    private String vendor;
    private String acc;
    private String schemaVersion;
    private String icon;
    private String type;
    private Descriptor descriptor;
    private DetailTemplate detailTemplate;
    private String accountId;
    private Boolean hasAccount;
    private Boolean canTestConnection;
    private String dataSourceType;
    private Boolean runNowSupported;
}

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Descriptor {
    private String displayName;
    private String description;
    private String docRef;
}

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DetailTemplate {
    private String type;
    private Descriptor descriptor;
    @NotEmpty(message = "{detailTemplate.properties.required}")
    private List<Property> properties;
}

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Property {
    private String id;
    private boolean required;
    private boolean disabled;
    private String validation;
    private String default_value;
    private String type;
    private Descriptor descriptor;
    private List<Option> options;
    private DependsOn depends_on;
    private boolean secret;
    private boolean disableOnEdit;
    private Integer minDays;
    private String helperText;
}

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Option {
    private String id;
    private String displayName;
}

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DependsOn {
    private String field;
    private String value;
}

Below is sample data of TemplateObj column which is to be stored in Spanner DB
  {
  "canTestConnection": true,
  "detailTemplate": {
    "properties": [
      {
        "descriptor": {
          "description": "Select multiple regions",
          "displayName": "Region",
          "docRef": "https://guide.com"
        },
        "id": "region",
        "options": [
          {
            "displayName": "us-east",
            "id": "us-east"
          },
          {
            "displayName": "canada",
            "id": "canada"
          }
        ],
        "required": true,
        "type": "multi-select"
      }
    ]
  },
  "descriptor": {
    "description": "Sample",
    "displayName": "Test Name",
    "docRef": "https://guide.com"
  },
  "hasAccount": true,
  "icon": "http://svg_link",
  "id": "abc",
  "schemaVersion": "1.0",
  "type": "xyz",
  "vendor": "Test"
}

I have also defined as below in my application.yaml file
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: com.google.cloud.spanner.hibernate.SpannerDialect

We were using @Type(type = "com.google.cloud.spanner.hibernate.types.SpannerJsonType") before while using hibernate 5.x version, but seems now just don't understand why the spanner custom column types is not there for json object
Any suggestions? I want to store the java object in json format.

The reason that the custom column type for JSON is not in the Hibernate 6.x dialect anymore, is that Hibernate 6.x has built-in support for JSON. There is therefore no longer need for a custom type for JSON.

The most likely reason for this error message is that there is a mismatch between your model classes and the JSON string that you are trying to deserialize. The ConnectorTemplate class seems valid, but contains two fields that are themselves structured classes; Descriptor and ConfigTemplate. Would you mind sharing those as well?

@KnutOlavLøite I have updated the description with required structured classes

@TanushreeBS Did you manage to solve it?
